# Trying to achieve thicker biceps using TRX and dumbbell curls

Tags: strength-training, biceps

I recently returned to strength training after years of only cardio. Today I mostly exercise with bodyweight and TRX, trying to avoid the muscle isolation method of classic free weigh exercises.

Back in the day when I did free weight training at the gym, I remember always having thin biceps, unproportioinal to a well developed triceps and upper body muscles.

Now I seem to be facing the same problem again, my biceps are not developing well and are visibly thin and unproportional to the rest of  my body.

For the back and biceps I do Pull-Ups, TRX High Row and TRX Bicep Curl (without twisting motion until now).

After some research I found out that the inner, short head of the bicep is responsible for twisting the forearm clockwise (from POV). I added a twist motion to the TRX Bicep Curl, and I added Dumbbell Curls.

Are there any other methods or exercises to "thicken" your biceps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I increase bicep width?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14483/how-can-i-increase-bicep-width)

Comment: I would only add that when it comes to specific muscle development, time under tension (TOT) is your friend.  You can increase time under tension by slowing down your repetitions, or even adding half repetitions (go all the way down, come up half-way, lower yourself again, go up all the way).  You've got to play with TOT, but keep over-training in mind.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is doing less biceps exercises and more back exercises. Doing pull-up variations, bent-over rows (barbell), any pulling exercise will get the job done. Pretty much the only bicep exercise I do are hammer curls.

Comment: I was about to update this. I think that my body reacts better to compound exercises than isolated ones. I replaced one of my TRX bicep exercises with chinups (under hand grip) and felt my biceps sore the next day. I recently injured my shoulder so I can't continue testing this, once I am back on track I'll post an update. I believe chin-ups are the way to go for biceps.