# What's the best way to increase bicep size and endurance

Tags: weightlifting

I'm a freshman in high school. I've been working out for a little over a year now.  I've finally reached a max of a 55 lb curl with one arm and now I would like to increase bicep size for my arms, which are only 11.5 inch when flexed. I would also like to increase endurance. Could anyone give me an ideal weight and rep range for increasing size and endurance?

Comment: Do 21-s, Search it up. Helped me put on some size.

Comment: I have lifted my whole life and never spent more than 20 mins in any week and 10-15 mins in a normal week on biceps.  I was never into body building buy had 16" biceps at a time and not much less now.  Want to get them bigger then focus on your core body.  I have yet to see a guy who can squat 500 pounds with small biceps.  I am not saying by squatting you will sprout huge bi's I am saying your body likes symmetry and your smaller muscle groups will get bigger faster as larger muscle groups grow.

Answer (score 3):

How your muscle looks like is defined by your genetics. However, what I have learned is that also working as hard on the antagonist helps actually the targeting muscle to grow too.

There was an Old school Bodybuilder with tremendous Arms (including Biceps): Chuck Sipes you can try some of his biceps and arm building routines... they might work for you.

https://www.t-nation.com/training/bodybuildings-original-superhero-chuck-sipes

General info: 
My recommendation for a bigger arm in general would be to work hard on your triceps too as it is nearly 2/3 of your arm to get a bigger look.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, look at gymnasts, they probably don't do bicep curls and have huge biceps.

I would recommend doing more back exercises that will engage your biceps like the following:

- bent-over barbell rows
- chin-ups
- pull-ups
- neutral grip pull-ups
- etc.

All those exercises will target your biceps on different angles as such they will get strong and big.

The hammer curl is the closest exercise you can get to isolating the brachialis muscle for getting it wider.

Comment: Source on the "wide" part? As I understand from other answers, bicep width is largely limited by genetics.

http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/14543/8828

Comment: Your bicep muscle will get bigger in every direction, not just peak if doing mostly curls.

Comment: Again, source? My point was that it's word against word. Repeating it doesn't change that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's the type of training I do. Only biceps exercise I do is hammer curls and my biceps are pretty thick. Feel free to lookup Olympic gymnasts training routines also.

Comment: Yeah, but that's just an anecdote. And it doesn't exclude the possibility that it's genetic.

Comment: The worst that can happen if you try my suggestion is that your biceps will still grow and you'll have a thick strong back. :)

Comment: I already have my routine, thanks. What I was looking for was scientific documentation that the bicep can in fact be made wider through exercise. I took the liberty of editing out that word from your answer, since it seems like conjecture. I would gladly welcome being wrong on this, so if you can dig up some study about it, that would be awesome.

Comment: I edited back in with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want to grow your biceps. There are multiple thing that you will have to keep in mind while saying that:

- **Bicep and tricep have to be in relation.** The strength on your bi's and tri's should be in a good relation to each other. If the bicep as example is a lot stronger you could develop elbow tendonitis and other joint related pains.
- **Tricep make up a lot of the arm.** Not only biceps, but also triceps make up a lot of your arms. You are saying you want bigger biceps. I used to be saying that too, but all I wanted were bigger arms. So triceps matter too.
- **The best muscle building exercises are compound movements.** Compound movements are movements which require multiple muscles. Some examples: rows, pull-ups, push-ups and squats. These movements have been scientifically proven to be better muscle builders than isolation movements (E.G. bicep curl).
- **For muscle growth you will need hypertrophy.** Hypertrophy is a process in the muscle which causes it to grow. You will get hypertrophy when training with a minimum of 8 reps. Most people say 8-12 reps will be the best, but there is scientific evidence that has proven 30 rep sets to be just as effective as 8-12 reps.

I'm sorry I wasn't able to put sources to my claims, but I hope I'll still be able to help.

Keep up the good work!